# Deleting session after log out

Tags: php, session, cookies, logout

I'm having a problem with deleting the sessions after the user logs out from the session. For example, Ben logs in using his username and password. Once logged in a screen appears showing "Welcome Ben" on the screen. Ben now logs off and a screen appears saying that the log-off has been successful. 
Lisa then logs in using her own username and password. After logging in a screen appears, however it still says "Welcome Ben" on the screen. Lisa refreshes the page and the "Welcome Bem" now changes to "Welcome Lisa". So it's obvious that the sessions aren't deleting properly after logging out. I'm just wondering if anyone can help with deleting the cookies after logging out

Here is the code that I am using:

```
<?php 
   session_start(); 
   $_SESSION['User']=" "; 
   $_SESSION['Name']=" "; 
   session_destroy(); 
   header("Location: login.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page 
?>
```

Comment: We can't help unless you provide your code.

Comment: Here is the code that i am using:
<?php

session_start();
 $_SESSION['User']=" "; 
 $_SESSION['Name']=" ";

 session_destroy();

header("Location: login.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page

?>

Comment: @HelidonaShabani Please edit your post and include the code there, with code formatting.

Comment: This may also be a simple caching problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be not deleting your cookie.On your index page use following code

```
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the session to blank and unsetting the session like so:

```
$_SESSION['User'] = '';
$_SESSION['Name'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['User']);
unset($_SESSION['Name']);
```

The unsets alone should be more than enough however.

Your finished script should look something like this:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['User']);
    unset($_SESSION['Name']);
    header("Location: login.php"); 
    // Redirecting To Home Page 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this its working :**

**logout.php**

```
  <?php
    session_start();

    unset($_SESSION["user"]);

    header("location:login.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: session_destroy is a bit overkill, what if there are other sessions that are storing data?

Comment: so simply use unset($_SESSION['user']); it will unset only that variable you want to remove from session.

Comment: If OP is having trouble with creating a logout script it would probably be useful if you put that in your answer

Comment: @DrRoach Sure,Its my pleasure..now check the answer. It will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['User']) AND isset($_SESSION['Name'])){
    unset($_SESSION['User']);
    unset($_SESSION['Name']);
    header("Location: login.php");
}
else{
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```